# MVC3 Unit Test Controller with Property Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, mocking

I have a MVC3 project that uses **property injection**.  Within my controllers I make a call to a service class.  As I mentioned it uses property injection (with **unity**) instead of resolving this through the constructor.  I have searched all over trying to find an example of a **unit test** that resolves these dependencies within my controller but everything seems to refer to constructer DI.  I’m getting frustrated.  Any help would be great.

Example of Controller:

```
  [Dependency]
  public ITrainingService trainingService { get; set; } 

  public ActionResult Index(MyTrainingView myTrainingView)
  {
    //Load all training items into view object
    myTrainingView.training = trainingService.getTraining(myTrainingView.trainingId);
    myTrainingView.videos = trainingService.getTrainingVideos(myTrainingView.trainingId);
    myTrainingView.visuals = trainingService.getTrainingVisuals(myTrainingView.trainingId);
    myTrainingView.exams = trainingService.getTrainingExams(myTrainingView.trainingId);

    return View(myTrainingView);
  }
```

I'm trying to resolve the trainingService when running my unit test.  I have found countless examples for mocking and resolving dependencies using constructor dependency but nothing when it comes to property injection.

Comment: the question should be more clear. I know what you've done, but not what do you want to achieve. what is exact point of frustration.

Comment: It would be helpful to post some code, even if it is incomplete. Show us what you want to set up, and the steps that you are missing.

Comment: I want to resolve the null pointer on my service class (which is an interface) within my controller.  I set this using property injection and can not find an example of a unit test that can achieve this.

Comment: @Aaron it's a public property, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rely on unity in your unit tests.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
    [Test]
    public void GetTrainingById()
    {
        var mockService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITrainingService>();
        mockService.Stub(service => service.getTraining(123)).Return(new ImaginaryClass());

        var sut = new TrainingController();
        sut.trainingService = mockService;

        var myTrainingView = new MyTrainingView();
        sut.Index(myTrainingView);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, myTrainingView.training);
    }
```

If you *must* use unity in your unit tests, you could just instantiate the `UnityContainer` in your test and use the `RegisterInstance` to register the objects you want to inject.

Comment: Thanks Bas, I appreciate it. Your post filled in the gaps that I was missing.  I got everything to work using both examples.